# How do I load sos through windbg in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, windbg, sos

I have an Asp.Net Core application which I would like to examine with windbg. How would I load the managed extensions, such as I would normally do with .loadby sos clr?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your setup, .Net Core can be installed in a variety of locations. So the first thing you should do it determine where the coreclr module is being loaded from. You can do this with `lm v m coreclr`. Check that sos.dll exists also exists at the path. If so, then a simple `.loadby sos coreclr` will work. If your sos.dll is located in a different location, you'll need to specify it manually: `.load <path>\sos.dll`. While there has only be a single RTM release so far, keep in mind that your CoreCLR and SOS versions need to match. You can verify the version in the lm output.